# Making all initial letters after line break capitalized

Tags: ruby

I'm supposed to change this:

```
1.               this string has leading space and too    MANY tabs and sPaCes betweenX
2.   the indiVidual Words in each Line.X
3.  each Line ends with a accidentally  aDDED   X.X
4.            in this lab you wilL WRITE code that "sAnITizES" this string by normalizingX
5.   ("normalizing" means   capitalizing sentences   and setting otherX
6.  characters to lower case)     and removes        the extra spaces between WOrds.X
```

Into this:

```
1.               This string has leading space and too    MANY tabs and sPaCes betweenX" 
2.   The indiVidual Words in each Line.X 
3.  Each Line ends with a accidentally  aDDED   X.X
4.            In this lab you wilL WRITE code that "sAnITizES" this string by normalizingX
5.   ("Normalizing" means   capitalizing sentences   and setting otherX
6.  Characters to lower case)     and removes         the extra spaces between WOrds.X
```

Here's what I have:

```
string.gsub!(/[([a-zA-Z]+)][^\n]*/) { |word| word.capitalize!} 
print string
```

Which results in this:

```
1.               This string has leading space and too    many tabs and sp
aces betweenx                                                             
2.   The individual words in each line.x                                   
3.  Each line ends with a accidentally  added   x.x                        
4.            In this lab you will write code that "sanitizes" this string 
by normalizingx                                                            
5.   ("normalizing" means   capitalizing sentences   and setting otherx    
6.  Characters to lower case)     and removes         the extra spaces betw
een words.x
```

The number are apart of the text that I'm targeting. Everything is one large string: there's just a `"\n"` before every number (`"1"`, `"2"`, `"3"`, `"4"`, etc.). Can someone point me in the right direction?

I can get the first letter of a new line to be capitalized, changing all the other letters to lower case.

Comment: Are those numbers real? `1.`, `2.`, and so on at the start of every line...? Is that really part of the target text?

Comment: Yeah, the number are real and apart of the text. That is really the target text.

Comment: Is it one big string, or multiple inputs?

Comment: 1 big string with a \n before every number (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

Comment: Does `MANY tabs and sPaCes betweenX` really need to turn into `"MANY tabs and sPaCes betweenX"`?

Comment: Also, does `and removes in       the` really need to turn into `and removes         the`?

Comment: No in both cases. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 2):

If you're updating file contents, you can read the file line by line, and update each line with

```
line.sub(/[a-z]/i) {|w| w.upcase}
```

If you're updating contents in a string, you can either split the string into lines and update it with the previous method, or do a `gsub` like this:

```
string.gsub(/^([^a-z]*)([a-z])/i) {|m| "#{$1}#{$2.upcase}"}

# regex: start of string, followed by zero or more non-alphabetic characters, followed by an alphabetic character
```

Comment: I'm a little confused with this. Wouldn't:

    line.sub(/[a-z]/i) {|w| w.upcase}

just upcase all words with lower case letters?

    string.gsub(/^([^a-z]*)([a-z])/i) {|m| "#{$1}#{$2.upcase}"}
   
for this, isn't it just looking for a lower cased letter and then another lower cased letter? How would it know that it's the first letter on a new line? After the word from string is loaded into m, what is it used for? What does $1 and $2 represent and why is it labeled $1 and $2? I'm not really too familiar with regular expressions or even Ruby all that much. Just trying to figure this out! :)

Comment: In the first case, Arie is sending each line to `sub`, not `gsub`, so at most one replacement is made per line.  As that regex matches a single character (upper-case or lower-case, because of the `i`), at most one letter will be capitalized per line, namely, the first one found, left-to-right. In the code with `gsub`, `([^a-z]*)` and `([a-z])` are capture groups #1 and #2, respectively. If a match is made by a capture group, it is assigned to a global variable associated with the capture group.  `$1` and `$2` contain the contents of the matches made by the two capture groups respectively.

Comment: @Blobert You may read some document before you actually start to work. You need to spend some time at the beginning, however, it will benefit your long term throughput. For this specific problem, you may read document for [Regexp](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html) and [Predefined Global Variables](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/globals_rdoc.html)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will be sure to read through it when I wake up tomorrow. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you started coding before you fully understood the logic you needed to turn into code, and that's causing all your other problems. If I were you I'd take a moment to describe to myself in plain English what the transformation rules are, and verify that they cover all cases with no exceptions, before I start coding. Doing that gave me the rule:

> For each line, capitalize the first letter which follows a "digit -
>   dot - 0 or more nonword character" sequence and which is followed by a
>   "any character - newline" sequence'

Then I translated those sequences into regex and was able to come up with a solution.

Some more hints:

- If you want to refer to a substring that matches a regex (for when you assemble the transformed string), use `$1`, `$2`, etc. [More info](http://www.ralfebert.de/archive/ruby/regex_cheat_sheet/).
- [rubular.com](http://rubular.com) is very useful for figuring out quickly where your regex starts to fail to match.

Here's my solution. You probably want to give yours another stab before looking at it.

```
str = <<EOF
1.               this string has leading space and too    MANY tabs and sPaCes betweenX
2.   the indiVidual Words in each Line.X
3.  each Line ends with a accidentally  aDDED   X.X
4.            in this lab you wilL WRITE code that "sAnITizES" this string by normalizingX
5.   ("normalizing" means   capitalizing sentences   and setting otherX
6.  characters to lower case)     and removes in       the extra spaces between WOrds.X
EOF

expected = <<EOF
1.               This string has leading space and too    MANY tabs and sPaCes betweenX
2.   The indiVidual Words in each Line.X
3.  Each Line ends with a accidentally  aDDED   X.X
4.            In this lab you wilL WRITE code that "sAnITizES" this string by normalizingX
5.   ("Normalizing" means   capitalizing sentences   and setting otherX
6.  Characters to lower case)     and removes in       the extra spaces between WOrds.X
EOF

# number - dot - >=1 nonword char - word char (this is what you need to upcase) - >=0 chars - newline
regex = /(\d\.\W+)(\w)(.*\n)/

str.gsub!(regex) { "#{$1}#{$2.upcase}#{$3}" }

puts expected
puts str == expected # true
```

Just some friendly advice from one self-taught programmer to another! :)

Comment: Thanks for the example! I will probably sleep on it and see if the solution comes to me in the next couple of days after some reading :P